# Spring MVC-Activation account by token-confirm account method return 404 error

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I am building an application with Spring,Hibernate,MVC, Maven and Tomcat.
I done everything like in this tutorial:

https://stackabuse.com/spring-security-email-verification-registration/

- So now i have this:
  -user register new account (validation etc)
  -user redirect to site when is confirmation that activation email has ben sent to his email address
  -in database i have correctly connection between user and his token
  -i receive an email correctly with unique token like this:

Hello user!!
To activate your account please click link below
http://localhost:8080/confirm-account?token=5e5aad4f-90c4-4f83-8f58-83b66d63659f

But when i copy and paste that link (i dont know why i dont have just link-i think its not important now) i got error 404. Just like api doesnt have this address.

And now i show you my controller with registration and confirm account

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) throws MessagingException {


    User user1 = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    User user2 = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (user1 != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.email", "Jest juz taki email w bazie!");

        return "register_user";

    }
    if (user2 != null) {

        bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "username.error", "Ta nazwa jest w użyciu");

        return "register_user";
    } else if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        return "register_user";

    } else {

        userRepository.save(user);

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(user);

        confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);


        emailSender.sendMail(user.getEmail(),"Konto w serwisie","<b>Witaj " + " "+ user.getFirstName()+"!</b>" +"<br> Dokonałeś rejestracji!" +
                "<br>Aby dokończyc proces musisz kliknąć w link który znajduje się poniżej:<br> "
        + "http://localhost:8080/confirm-account?token=" + confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());

        model.addAttribute("confirmationMessage", "Pomyślnie utworzyłeś konto!Potwierdzenie wysłane na adres" + user.getEmail());

        return "success";
    }
}
```

And confirmation

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/confirm-account", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String confirmUserAccount(Model model, @RequestParam("token")String confirmationToken)
{
    ConfirmationToken token = confirmationTokenRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

    if(token != null)
    {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(token.getUser().getEmail());
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return "accountVerified";
    }
    else
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "The link is invalid or broken!");
        return "error";
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which URL are you calling for `/add`? The otherone should be exactly the same, instead of `/add` it shoudl be `/confirm-account` (assuming both methods are in the same controller!).

Comment: My God... this is it... I just have it in controller which have /user address... Now confirmation link with localhost:8080/user/confirm is working! THank you! I just cant believe!

Comment: Just use the builder, that will prevent you from errors like this.

Comment: Thank you very much! It saves my day! And now i will use it for sure :D

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `http://localhost:8080/confirm-account?token=5e5aad4f-90c4-4f83-8f58-83b66d63659f` is the actual URL. Unless your application is deployed as ROOT in your application server. It probably should be something like `http://localhost:8080/<app-name-version>/confirm-account?token=5e5aad4f-90c4-4f83-8f58-83b66d63659f`.

Instead of using `String` concat to construct a URL I would strongly suggest to use an `UriComponentsBuilder` to make your life easier.

Something like this.

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(request)
                 .path("/confirm-account");
                 .queryParam("token", confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken()).toUriString();
```

Then use this `url` to add it to your email text instead of hardcoding the URL in there.

**NOTE:** instead of creating the `UriComponentsBuilder` yourself you can also add it as a argument to the request handling method.

Comment: This builder will be great, thanks. But i change the root link from <app name> to just localhost:8080/ - so i think its not the question.

Comment: Use the builder, even if it is to prevent issues. The 404 is a clear sign that your URL simplu doesn't match. So either you aren't using the correct URL and haven't changed the mapping, or you mis some servlet mapping part in the URL depending on how your `DispatcherServlet` is being mapped.